# Giving permissions for activate later to content-authors role

Tags: permissions, workflow, aem

I have a CQ 5.6.1 instance with the default out of the box setup for users and groups. The "Activate Later" button is not accessible to users in the content-authors group however "Activate" button works fine and kicks off the activation workflow. How can I give that group permissions to use activate later and fire off the Scheduled Activation Workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked and in my case the `Activate Later` button is accessible for a newly created user who is a member of `content-authors` group.

Looking into the code (`libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin/actions`) these are possible causes of the disabled functionality:

- lack of replicate privilege
- page is locked
- no page has been selected in grid

The latter two are common for `Activate` and `Activate Later` yet the replicate privilege is surprisingly checked for `Activate Later` functionality only.

Please make sure you have proper ACLs on the page. You can easily use CRXDE or CRX Explorer tools to validate the effective permissions.

Comment: Looks like we we're playing with permissions for content-author and removed replicate. We need to keep that right from content authors for our workflows. So we ended up removing the replicate permission check for activate later. Thanks for your help.